# How can I retrieve result from my country in here maps?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I use this function to retrieve results of the user search of a destination, but this gets all results from the world, how can I distinct results from certain country

```
 function getPlace() {
            setLoadingIcons(true);
            var places = platform.getPlacesService(),
                entryPoint = H.service.PlacesService.EntryPoint,
                txtSearch = document.getElementById('txtSearch');
            places.request(entryPoint.SEARCH, { 'at': _HEREmap.getCenter().lat + ',' + _HEREmap.getCenter().lng, 'q': txtSearch.value, 'size': 5 }, function (response) {
                var items = response.results.items;
                var placeHTML = '<div><a href="#" onclick="return showMapForDistination({LAT}, {LNG});"> <input hidden name="lat" value="{LAT}"><input hidden name="lat" value="{LNG}">{TITLE} <img src="Images/navigation Icon.png" id="arr" width="15" /> </a></div>';
                var html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    html += placeHTML.replace("{TITLE}", items[i].title).replace("{LAT}", items[i].position[0]).replace("{LNG}", items[i].position[1]);
                }
                document.getElementById('divSearchResult').innerHTML = html + '<div id="divCnclBtn"><img src="Images/Cancel Button.png" id="cnclBtn" onclick="onSearchTextBlur();"></div>';
                document.getElementById('divSearchResult').style['display'] = 'block';
                setLoadingIcons(false);
            }, function (resp) {
                //console.log('ERROR: ' + resp);
                setLoadingIcons(false);
            });


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what I can tell in the Places API reference, it's surprisingly hard to do...

First, instead of 'at' use ['in' with a bounding box](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics/location-contexts.html#location-contexts__bbox-format) (i.e. the bounding box of the country) to get rough filtering to work.
When you get results, look at each [place result's address](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics_api/object-link.html#place-link) property and filter them by [address.country](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics_api/object-address.html) (or address.countryCode).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since you don't know the situation i was put in, I don't care your opinion on me (and even if you know, I don't care too).
Upvoting and marking your answer as the best.

Comment: Do you know a way to add country by name instead of boundaries coords? (*feel free to not answer)

Comment: Sorry, if I came across impolite. I was not referring to your situation, I was surprised that an easy use case as yours does not seem to have an easy solution in the API, when reading through the documentation. I could not find a way to filter by country name, which is why I proposed the bounding box solution.

Comment: Seriously, I meant no offense. I removed the line with my personal opinion to keep the answer purely technical and to avoid misinterpretation.